# set dynamic ip in security group, in AWS hosting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ip, hosting

I have created a security group in aws.amazon.com hosting.
I have set SSH to custom IP.
My problem is that my IPs are dynamic with in a range:

For example,

```
217.206.204.200
217.206.203.215
217.206.201.295
```

I want to create one  rule for SSH custom IPs. So that all IPs have starting 217.206 can connect to server.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
217.206.0.0/16
```

This expression in the "Custom IP" box would allow every IP from 217.206.0.0 through 217.206.255.255, inclusive.

This is called CIDR notation.

The numbet after the slash is the prefix.  An IPv4 address is 32 bits wide.  The prefix indicates which bits of the address being compared must match the address specified.  In this case, if the first 16 bits of the address of the connecting machine are "217" followed by "206" then the remaining bits of the address can be anything, and the rule will match that source IP.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation